# OpenX Revive Adserver targeting with site variables

Tags: php, openx, advertisement-server

I'm using Revive Adserver on my web-site and I'm having a problem with targeting.

Here is my invocation code

```
var m3_u = (location.protocol=='https:'?'https://ads.pingola.ru/www/delivery/ajs.php':'http://ads.pingola.ru/www/delivery/ajs.php');
var m3_r = Math.floor(Math.random()*99999999999);
if (!document.MAX_used) document.MAX_used = ',';
document.write ("<scr"+"ipt type='text/javascript' src='"+m3_u);
document.write ("?zoneid={{item_zone_id}}");
{% if target_params != ''%}
document.write ("{{target_params}}");
{% endif %}
document.write ('&amp;cb=' + m3_r);
if (document.MAX_used != ',') document.write ("&amp;exclude=" + document.MAX_used);
document.write (document.charset ? '&amp;charset='+document.charset : (document.characterSet ? '&amp;charset='+document.characterSet : ''));
document.write ("&amp;loc=" + escape(window.location));
if (document.referrer) document.write ("&amp;referer=" + escape(document.referrer));
if (document.context) document.write ("&amp;context=" + escape(document.context));
if (document.mmm_fo) document.write ("&amp;mmm_fo=1");
document.write ("'><\/scr"+"ipt>");
```

This the request url of this code `delivery/ajs.php?zoneid=15&category=cars&make=Mazda&model=2&body=hatchback&price=640000&year=2013&vol=1500&fuel=gasoline&cond=excellent&kpp=automatic&color=red&isNew=1&cb=1702326047&charset=UTF-8&loc=http`

If don't set up delivery options banner shows up and everything fine. If I set up delivery limitation Site - Varieble (f.e. category is equel to cars) banner doesn't show up. Interesting fact - if I set up category is different from cars banner shows up.

Comment: So if you have no category or something other than `cars` it works? Are you sure that's the correct name then, maybe it's `Cars`

Comment: It works for any category. And yes I'm sure that is correct name. I checked that a lot.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.openx.com/ad_server/index.html#custom_variables_in_ad_calls.html), you have to prefix the variables with `c.` in the request:

> - To distinguish it from other types of ad call parameters, custom KVPs must be prefixed with the `c.` namespace.
>
>   For example: `c.topic=sports` (where `topic` is the key and `sports` is the value)

So I guess the request should look something like this:
`delivery/ajs.php?zoneid=15&c.category=cars&c.make=Mazda&c.model=2&c.body=hatchback&c.price=640000&c.year=2013&c.vol=1500&c.fuel=gasoline&c.cond=excellent&c.kpp=automatic&c.color=red&c.isNew=1&cb=1702326047&charset=UTF-8&loc=http`

Comment: Side note: I am also having problems with OpenX targeting even with the built-in parameters like "Client - Useragent"! So maybe you should check whether these parameters work to see if the targeting works in general.

Comment: Revive adserver behaves different, no prefix is required.